# Does Google filter on auto suggestion to avoid causing offence?

Tags: autocomplete, google

I've discovered that [Google](http://www.google.com) removes auto suggestion for some phrases on their service. 
For example try googling:

- women should
- men should
- women are
- men are

The auto suggestions will disappear after you write "women " or "men ". The same goes when googling "children ".

It's the same when trying to Google "wives should", however "wives are" (which returns some very horrific suggestions) and "husbands should" does provide suggestions.

I'm not sure what the rational is behind this. Could it be because the returned result is so overwhelming that Google has decided to remove the auto suggestions (not likely)? Or could it be because they're afraid of being perceived as promoting labeling of certain gender groups / domestic roles (children doesn't fit into this though I feel)?

Does anyone have any insight on this? Has Google made a statement regarding this behavior? And can one draw conclusions on how this affects the UX, that is limiting functionality to serve another purpose separate from the service?

Comment: "which returns some very horrific suggestions" Careful what you say - ["the search queries that you see as part of Autocomplete are a reflection of the search activity of users and the content of web pages. You may also see predictions from relevant searches you’ve done in the past"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230?hl=en)  Just sayin' :)

Comment: @RogerAttrill haha, OK, good one. Well, I can ensure you that my browsing history does not entail content that would produce suggestions such as "wives are like jokes", "wives are the weaker vessel" and "wives are to submit to their husbands". So I'm quite sure there are some other power at be here.

Comment: The horror! What would happen if wives would submit to their husbands, and husbands would "dwell with them with understanding, giving honor to the wife, as to the weaker vessel" -- horrific doesn't quite describe that genderpocalypse.

Comment: @EricWilson come again?

Comment: @AndroidHustle: Eric Wilson is being somewhat sarcastic, but he's trying to give the actual context around two of the fragments that horrified you (biblical context, which when completed has a very different tone than the two fragments do individually).

Comment: I wonder if the results of this experiment are different depending on whether you're A) signed in to google and B) have SafeSearch enabled or disabled? I would suspect that if SafeSearch is disabled, and google can tell that you have it disabled in your profile (i.e. you're logged in to google), then it will give you different search results, since it assumes you're not going to be easily offended by pornography or adult-oriented search results.

Comment: with regard to "wives are" returning "horrific sugestions", more then half of those are biblical phrases (the weaker vessel and to submit to their husbands). So although that may sound horrific to you, they are definitely very familiar (and mostly) unoffensive phrases to Christians (and to those that understand the context).

Comment: I never use the automatic search. You can turn this off permanently by adding webhp? to the URL

Comment: @n00b: Something offensive doesn't become non-offensive just because it appears in a magical book. Or, put differently, presence of a bad idea in a sacred book does not exempt the bad idea from being judged as bad.

Comment: For an idea of the motivation for doing this: Google's auto suggestion is there as a convenience feature to help users more quickly find something useful they might be looking for. It's not there as a platform for making a statement (especially a loaded or hate-oriented one) or for reinforcing particular social "values" (or rather social depravity, as it may be). The latter has both commercial (public backlash) and legal liability issues associated with it, and Google is making a reasonable decision to eliminate this unreasonable risk.

Comment: @R I think the original point was that "horrific" is hyperbolic, offensive or not. Secondly, the flip side of the coin is that this just means Google isn't censoring the Bible in this case, and by the tones of this question you find censorship wrong or at least warranting scrutiny, so seems you should be fine with that. (And if not, [there's always this book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451).)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google actually removes autosuggestions for specific searches.
In which cases?

**[Searchengineland writes:](http://searchengineland.com/how-google-instant-autocomplete-suggestions-work-62592)**

> Were things being removed?
>   Yes, and for these specific reasons, Google says:
>
> - Hate or violence related suggestions
> - Personally identifiable information in suggestions
> - Porn & adult-content related suggestions
> - Legally mandated removals
> - Piracy-related suggestions

I've googled this list but I haven't been able to find the original page on Google Help Center.

On Google Help Center **[you can find this page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230?hl=en)** about "Autocomplete" where Google says:

> Our algorithm automatically detects and excludes **a small set of search terms**. But it’s designed to reflect the diversity of our users’ searches and content on the web. So just like the web, the search terms shown may seem strange or surprising.

Comment: At this page is quoted a previous version of the Google Help Center page about "Autocomplete" I've linked above: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/v4NDcIxGfe0 . It seems like it contained this sentence: "We aim to provide you with relevant search queries, but we exclude a narrow class of search queries related to pornography, violence, and hate speech" (the sentence is now gone).

Comment: hmm, OK, so that being said one can assume that Google relates searches based on "women ", "men " and "children " to fall under one of those categories? a bit surprising actually. I personally think monitoring the suggestions would have been enough, something that probably should be done with some other phrases (such as the one I listed in the OP).

Comment: I guess the reason is that the most popular (and therefore autosuggested) result for "women should" or "men are" or "children are" were often close to hate speech or even worse. We know gender issues are particularly delicate matters, likely to drive a lot of criticism towards Google if misused.
I think monitoring wouldn't be enough too. You can filter most words, but what happens if even for just 10 minutes Google suggest you a sex-related keyword when searching "Children are"?
A single mistake can cost too much - so it's easier for Google to remove the autocomplete at all.

Comment: Sounds like a sound solution.

Comment: They're not too quick with it though: http://eastasiastudent.net/china/google-suggest-chinese-people-eating-babies